# How to determine tic tac toe winner using this code?

Tags: python

Right now, the code does everything from asking the player's name to ending the game when the grid is full. I'm completely stumped on how to add to the code so if someone gets three in a row, it can say who won and then end the game.

```
while True:
    from ezgraphics import GraphicsWindow
    #Draw Tic Tac Toe Grid
    def draw_tic_tac_toe(size):
        #Drawing the game board!!
        title= "Tic Tac Toe"
        win = GraphicsWindow(size, size)
        win.setTitle(title)
        win_canvas = win.canvas()
        w, h = size, size
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = 0, h/3, w, h/3
        win_canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        win_canvas.drawLine(x1, 2*y1, x2, 2*y2)
        win_canvas.drawLine(y1, x1, y1, x2)
        win_canvas.drawLine(2*y1, x1, 2*y1, x2)
        return(win)
    
    #Set all the boxes in the tic tac toe grid
    def set_gamebox(win):
        #set h to 300
        h = win.canvas().width()
        #SET COORDINATES FOR THE 9 BOXES
        #I renamed h/3, 2*h/3, and h to make things easier to read
        A = int(h/3)
        B = int(2*h/3)
        C = h
        game_box =  [[[0,0], [A,0], [A,A], [0,A]]] #GAME BOX 1
        #[[[0,0], [A,0], [A,A], [0,A]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[A,0], [B,0], [A,A], [B,A]]] #GAME BOX 2
        #[[[A,0], [B,0], [A,A], [B,A]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[B,0], [C,0], [B,A], [C,A]]] #GAME BOX 3
        #[[[B,0], [C,0], [B,A], [C,A]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[0,A], [A,A], [0,B], [A,B]]] #GAME BOX 4
        #[[[0,A], [A,A], [0,B], [A,B]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[A,A], [B,A], [A,B], [B,B]]] #GAME BOX 5
        #[[[A,A], [B,A], [A,B], [B,B]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[B,A], [C,A], [B,B], [C,B]]] #GAME BOX 6
        #[[[B,A], [C,A], [B,B], [C,B]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[0,B], [A,B], [0,C], [A,C]]] #GAME BOX 7
        #[[[0,B], [A,B], [0,C], [A,C]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[A,B], [B,B], [A,C], [B,C]]] #GAME BOX 8
        #[[[A,B], [B,B], [A,C], [B,C]]]
        game_box = game_box + [[[B,B], [C,B], [B,C], [C,C]]] #GAME BOX 9
        #[[[B,B], [C,B], [B,C], [C,C]]]
        return(game_box)

    #draw x on the board
    def draw_x(x, y): 
        w.canvas().drawLine(x, y, x + w3 / 2, y + w3 / 2)
        w.canvas().drawLine(x + w3 / 2, y, x, y + w3 / 2)
        return(w)
    #draw o on the board
    def draw_o(x, y):
        radius = w3 / 2
        w.canvas().drawOval(x, y, radius, radius)
        return(w)

    def draw_X(box):
        if (box == 1):
            x1 = w3 / 4
            x2 = w3 / 4
        if (box == 2):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3
            x2 = w3 / 4
        if (box == 3):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
            x2 = w3 / 4
        if (box == 4):
            x1 = w3 / 4
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3
        if (box == 5):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3
        if (box == 6):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3
        if (box == 7):
            x1 = w3 / 4 
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
        if (box == 8):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
        if (box == 9):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
        return x1, x2

    def draw_O(box):
        if (box == 1):
            x1 = w3 / 4
            x2 = w3 / 4
        if (box == 2):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3
            x2 = w3 / 4
        if (box == 3):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
            x2 = w3 / 4
        if (box == 4):
            x1 = w3 / 4
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3
        if (box == 5):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3
        if (box == 6):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3
        if (box == 7):
            x1 = w3 / 4 
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
        if (box == 8):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
        if (box == 9):
            x1 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
            x2 = w3 / 4 + w3 * 2
        return x1, x2

    w = draw_tic_tac_toe(300)
    game_boxes = set_gamebox(w)
    w3 = w.canvas().width() / 3

    def getBox(x, y):
        for n in range(9):
            if (x > (n % 3) * w3) and ( x < ((n % 3) + 1) * w3 ) and (y > int(n / 3) * w3) and (y < (int(n / 3) + 1) * w3) :           
                return n + 1


    playerA = input("Player A, what is your name?: ")
    playerB = input("Player B, what is your name?: ")


    choice = input("Who wants to go first? " +playerA+ "? Or " +playerB+"?: ")
    if choice == playerA:
        print(playerA + " goes first!")
        
    else:
        print(playerB + " goes first!")

    def secondPlayer():
        if choice == playerA:
            return playerB
        else:
            return playerA
        
    sign_choice= input(choice + ", do you want to play x or o: ")

    def otherSignChoice():
        if sign_choice == 'x':
            return 'o'
        else:
            return 'x'
        
    print(choice + " will play " + sign_choice +".\n"+ secondPlayer() +" will play " + otherSignChoice()+ ".")


    i = 0
    while i < 9:
        pt = w.getMouse()
        print(pt, getBox(pt[0], pt[1]))
        nBox = getBox(pt[0], pt[1])
        if sign_choice == 'o':
            if (i % 2 == 0):
                o1, o2 = draw_O(nBox)
                draw_o(o1, o2)
                print('o')
            else:
                x1, x2 = draw_X(nBox)
                draw_x(x1, x2)
                print('x')
            i += 1
            
        else:
            if (i % 2 == 0):
                x1, x2 = draw_X(nBox)
                draw_x(x1, x2)
                print('x')
            else:
                o1, o2 = draw_O(nBox)
                draw_o(o1, o2)
                print('o')
            i += 1
    while True:
        answer = str(input('Do you want to play again? (y/n): '))
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Game Over")
        break
```

Comment: Your code is 95% about drawing lines. What really is missing here is a game representation in memory, such as a list or dictionary, so that you know where moves have been played. Currently the code has no way to know what has been played, and users can even make invalid moves, placing their X or O on an already occupied box. So before even asking about how to detect a win, you should focus on how to represent the game and avoid such illegal moves. This is something you should even do *before* thinking about *output* (like all the drawing).

Comment: @trincot Thank you for the info. It really helps a lot. I know this is what I'm supposed to do but I'm just not sure on how to do it. However, I'll do some research and try to figure it out. Also I'll fix the other stuff you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code lacks an essential part: a *representation* of the game in memory. Currently your code has no knowledge of the moves that have already been played, and it cannot verify whether a user attempts to play in a box that already has a symbol from a previous move.

I will not adjust your existing code, but instead show you how you should start:

- Create a class that focuses only on maintaining the game's state: it should provide the functions to play a move, to verify that a move is valid, to check whether the game has ended, whether it is a draw or has a winner, ... None of this needs to know about the *visualisation* of the game, but it will be a class that you can use whether you have a graphical user interface for playing the game, or just a terminal input/output, or a keyboard driven interface, ...etc, ...etc.
- An instance of that class should have attributes that remember what has been played and what the current game looks like. But this should be as simple as possible. For instance, that representation could be a standard list of length 9, where each element of that list indicates with a number or a string what the state is of that cell in the game. "X" could be for when the first player has played there, "O" for when the second player has played there, and then anything else to indicate the cell is still free. The latter could be a space, or -- why not -- the numerical identifier of that cell (0, 1, 2, ... 8).
- The class could also provide a very, very basic string representation, so at least you can debug with `print` statements.
- The next step is to create the flow of a game -- the driver code: it will have the loop where in each iteration a move is played, and an inner loop where you keep getting the user's next move until that input is *valid*. The outer loop should exit when the game is over. This code should be simple and rely on the class for any game-logic.

So here is an implementation of that class and a very simple version of the driver code, which uses simple `input()` and `print()` calls for the user interface. It will be your job to replace that input/output with the graphical user interface you are using (where input is coming partly from the mouse, and output consists of drawing lines).

```
class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = list("012345678")
        self.moves = []

    def __repr__(self):
        s = " ".join(self.board)
        return "\n".join([s[:5], s[6:11], s[12:]])

    def is_free(self, spot):
        return 0 <= spot < 9 and self.board[spot] not in "XO"

    def turn(self):
        return "XO"[len(self.moves) % 2]

    def move(self, spot):
        if not self.is_free(spot):
            raise ValueError("This is not a valid move")
        symbol = self.turn()
        self.board[spot] = symbol
        self.moves.append(symbol)

    def winner(self):
        # Check each line of 3 for a win
        for a, b, c in ((0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(0,4,8),(2,4,6)):
            if self.board[a] == self.board[b] == self.board[c] and self.board[a] in "XO":
                return self.board[a]
        return ""

    def is_draw(self):
        return not self.winner() and len(self.moves) == 9

    def over(self):
        return self.winner() or self.is_draw()

# Play one game
game = TicTacToe()
while not game.over():
    print(game) # Here you would draw the game
    while True: # Repeat until valid move is entered
        # Here you would get the mouse click, ...etc
        spot = int(input(f"Choose the spot for {game.turn()}: "))
        if game.is_free(spot):
            break
        print("That is not a valid spot...")
    game.move(spot)

print(game)
if game.is_draw():
    print("It's a draw!")
else:
    print(f"{game.winner()} won the game!")
```

Answer (score -3):

You can check every row to see if any of them contains the same three letters.

By the way, don't be surprised if this question is closed soon. Stack Overflow doesn't welcome asking for help about your own program should work. No one is going to write that code for you.

Comment: I just need an idea on how to do it. Not expecting anyone to do it for me. It's a huge mess anyway. Also thank you, you gave me an idea.

Comment: Not read it properly but when does this loop exit - `while i < 9:` (remember you need to exit to end the game)? Also try to put all your imports at the very top, followed by all your functions, outside of any loops :D

Comment: @JJScene sorry, I misunderstood you then. I thought that you're asking for more specific code, and not a general idea, because you've included your existing code and asked "how to add the code".

Comment: @TimKirkwood At the end the question is asked to play the game again or end it. Not really sure how it works, but it works.

Comment: @JJScene sure but that while i< 9 is presumable saying keep going until the board is full right?  Whereas you're saying you have a specific condition where you want the game to end (3 in a row).  So you need to put that condition in.  Also try not to write code you don't understand (although we all do it especially at the start dont worry) - if you don't know why everything does what it does you wont be able to test it properly because you dont know what everything should do, and in general youre more likely to get bugs :(